# Is this inequality true? $|\hat{f}(0)| \leq \|f\|_{L^{\infty}}$

Tags: complex-analysis, functional-analysis

I am looking for a proof of the following inequality (if it is true)?
$$|\hat{f}(0)| \leq \|f\|_{L^{\infty}},$$
where $f(\theta)$ is a $L^{2}(\mathbb{T})$ function on the unit circle with the Fourier modes, $\hat{f}(n)\in\mathbb{C}$, with negative frequencies being zero ($\hat{f}(n) = 0$ if $n<0$). Namely,
$$f(\theta) = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\hat{f}(n) e^{in\theta}, \qquad \sum_{n=0}^{\infty}|\hat{f}(n)|^2 < \infty.$$

Comment: Hint: what happens if you take the absolute value inside the integral defining $\hat{f}(n)$?

Comment: Thanks, I think that with your hint I saw the idea $$|\hat{f}(0)|=|\int_0^{2\pi}f(\theta)\frac{d\theta}{2\pi}|\leq \int_0^{2\pi}|f(\theta)|\frac{d\theta}{2\pi}\leq  \int_0^{2\pi}\|f(\theta)\|_{L^{\infty}}\frac{d\theta}{2\pi}= \|f(\theta)\|_{L^{\infty}}$$